# Let samba broadcast through UFW?

Tags: server, samba, 17.04, firewall, ufw

I've got UFW running on a file server. I can connect via Samba if I specify the IP address, but it doesn't show up in any networked computer's lists, either PC or Mac.

I'm assuming I'm missing some part of the config process. Here's what I have:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere on tun0           ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   ALLOW       10.0.1.0/24               
Samba                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Samba                      ALLOW       10.0.1.0/24               
plexmediaserver            ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere (v6) on tun0      ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Samba (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
plexmediaserver (v6)       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0          
209.58.139.47              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on tun0
```

I'm sure this is a mess... But I'm new to using UFW and could use some guidance on how to grant Samba complete access to my local network (basically bypassing the UFW entirely, which is kind of where I want to be for both it and Plex).

Server is running Ubuntu Server 17.04.

Comment: you have to allow the ports in ufw TCP 139,445 and UDP 137,138 then on your pc or windows make sure you enable network discovery it will automatically allow you to view the networks to login and view the samba shared folder alike

Comment: Given that you can connect to the server if you specify the IP address, I think it's safe to assume that UFW is not blocking Samba and that UFW is not your problem.  I would suspect that the issue is your /etc/samba/smb.conf file.  Have you set `wins support =yes` to use the Ubuntu wins server, or set `wins server = w.x.y.x` to specify the address of a wins server?

Comment: I just fought this problem and Charles Green is correct. Oddly the server still won't show up on some old 32 bit systems but it's good on all newer Ubuntu and Windoze systems.

Comment: I'm pretty certain the issue is UFW if only because it behaved as expected before I had set up the UFW.